# Database relationship (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, relation

I am not sure, if i did the right relation between my tables. I do not know, if i have to use 1:n or n:1, or am I completely wrong? I had joins in my course only and not really the relationships between the tables.

Here is my screenshot from mysql workbench: [click](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3799/kirim6fo_jpg.htm)

Would be nice, if someone can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest connecting table **user->user_id** and table **search_form->user_id**, and of course table **user->user_id** and table **find_form->user_id** with 1:n.

According to the fieldnames it makes the most sense.

Comment: Yes. This is what i mean.

Comment: I am not sure, where the "1" should be?

Comment: But i am sure, buddy. If you want connect the fourth table in a similar way. This should make it complete.